# Is HyperSync possible with a flash on a PocketWizard Mini TT1?

Tags: canon-5d-mark-ii, hotshoe-flash, pocket-wizard

I recently bought a PocketWizard Mini TT1 and a Flex TT5. When attaching a 430EX on the FlexTT5, I can set the shutter at 1/8000 and still get a correct exposure thanks to [HyperSync](http://www.pocketwizard.com/inspirations/technology/hypersync_fpsync/).

However, when attaching the 430EX on top of the TT1 (so, on-camera with the TT1 in between and without using the TT5), the camera doesn't let me choose shutter speeds faster than 1/200, as if there was no HyperSync.

With the TT5 this works (on-camera). Is this by design? 
Do I need to use the Flex to get HyperSync on the camera-mounted flash (with or without additional radio-triggered flash)?

**EDIT:** as it seems also the TT5 forces 1/200 after the first calibration shot.

I'd prefer to use the MiniTT1 in such a configuration as it is much smaller...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HyperSync is designed to work over radio. The hot-shoe on transceiver is pretty much directly connected to camera underneath - if you have a flash there, you have to enable HSS on it to use shutter speeds over X-sync.

Comment: would the 580EX II be able to support fast shutter speeds by itself?

Comment: Yes, but only as HSS mode. HyperSync is a PocketWizard feature, Canon stuff won't do that on its own, or even when communicating through the TT1.